# Insert values in inheritance tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design, sql-insert

```
CREATE TABLE projeto.Person (
    Person_Code         INT IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
    birthDate           DATE                NOT NULL,
    Name                VARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Person_Code)
)

CREATE TABLE projeto.Student (
    Student_Code        INT REFERENCES projeto.Person (Person_Code),
    payment             INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Student_Code),
)
CREATE TABLE projeto.teacher (
    payment             INT                 NOT NULL,
    teacher_Code        INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (teacher_Code),
    CHECK (payment > 350)
)
```

How do I insert values ​​in student, paying attention that a student has all person attributes? e.g. student has `name`, `birth_date` etc.

I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO projeto.Person VALUES 
    ('1961-03-26', John Adam')
```

but this only adds in a person, and I can't tell if its a student or not.

Comment: Could you expand your question such that we can see how you know whether you are inserting a student or a teacher... i.e. do you have a variable?

Comment: Also I think you have an error, an additional `'` after `adam`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess its how to get the recently inserted `Person_Code` that you are asking? In which case use `scope_identity()`.

```
declare @BirthDate date, @Name varchar(50), @Payment int, @IsStudent bit, @IsTeacher bit, @NewPersonCode int;

-- SET THE RELEVANT VARIABLE VALUES

-- Insert person
insert into projeto.Person (BirthDate, [Name])
  select @BirthDate, @Name;

-- Get the Person_Code of the new person record
set @NewPersonCode = scope_identity();

-- Insert Student record if a student
insert into projeto.Student (Student_Code, Payment)
  select @NewPersonCode, @Payment
  where @IsStudent = 1;

-- Insert Teacher record if a teacher
insert into projeto.Teacher (Teacher_Code, Payment)
  select @NewPersonCode, @Payment
  where @IsTeacher = 1;
```